# Get geometry column back when counting points in polygon using PostGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, geometry

I have two PostGIS tables: `earthquakes` and `borders`, which contain point data on earthquake locations, and polygons of countries in the world respectively.

I want to try and count the earthquakes within each country, and I've managed to do this using the following SQL:

```
SELECT ch01.borders.name, COUNT(ch01.earthquakes.geom) as count FROM ch01.borders, ch01.earthquakes
WHERE ST_Contains(ch01.borders.geom, ch01.earthquakes.geom)
GROUP BY ch01.borders.name ORDER BY count DESC;
```

This gives me a nice ordered table showing the number of earthquakes in each country. However, I'd like to produce a map of the world in QGIS, with each country shaded relative to the number of earthquakes occurring within its borders - but to do that, I need to get a geometry column back from the SQL query (it seems that I'll also need a primary key, but I'll cross that bridge later).

I tried simply selecting the geometry column in the SQL:

```
SELECT ch01.borders.geom, ch01.borders.name, COUNT(ch01.earthquakes.geom) as count FROM ch01.borders, ch01.earthquakes
WHERE ST_Contains(ch01.borders.geom, ch01.earthquakes.geom)
GROUP BY ch01.borders.name ORDER BY count DESC;
```

but that gives me an error saying:

```
ERROR: column "borders.geom" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

The problem is: I don't want to aggregate or group by the geometry, I just want to return the geometry for the rows that I've got. How can I do this?

Comment: Does each `borders.name` have a matching `borders.geom`? If so you can do a `GROUP BY ch01.borders.name, borders.geom` and it should return both name and geom.

Comment: That seems like the simplest way to do it, but it doesn't seem to work for me. Adding the extra column to the group-by doesn't seem to change the results at all. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: @robintw Don't forget to add "geom" to your SELECT clause  . If you try both solutions, I'd be interested to know the query times.

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use a `WITH` query, also known as a [Common Table Expression](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/queries-with.html).  You can use the first query you wrote (lightly modified) in the `WITH` query and then join it to your "borders" table. Assuming the PRIMARY KEY for "borders" is "gid", it could look like this:

```
WITH eqs_per_border AS (
  SELECT
    ch01.borders.gid AS gid,
    COUNT(*) AS eq_count
  FROM
    ch01.borders,
    ch01.earthquakes
  WHERE ST_Contains(ch01.borders.geom, ch01.earthquakes.geom)
  GROUP BY ch01.borders.name 
)
SELECT
  ch01.borders.gid AS "ROWID",
  ch01.borders.name AS border_name,
  eqs_per_border.eq_count AS eq_count,
  ch01.borders.geom AS geom
FROM 
  ch01.borders,
  eqs_per_border
WHERE ch01.borders.gid = eqs_per_border.gid
ORDER BY count DESC
```

A couple of notes: First, use a `JOIN` on the second query if that feels more natural. Second, it is not necessary to put the "ROWID" alias on the "gid" column. It's just a habit I developed from a trick to get QGIS to respect SpatiaLite views.